# Set default time in bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I set the default Hours and minutes as "00:00". Here I want to set only time not date. I am using the following code for datetimepicker. In this code how can I set the default time as "00:00"?

```js
    $('#timepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({
    format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",          
    pickSeconds:false,   
 }).on("show",function(e) {
  if($("#from_Date"+ rowIndx).val() == ""){                                                     $('#timepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker("setDate", "");     
 }                
 }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    isExtraTcAmountDateChanged = "Y";
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap datetimepicker uses moment library so make use of it like this,

```
var dateNow = new Date();
$('#current_date').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate:moment(dateNow).hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "H:i",
    defaultTime: '00:00',
    pickSeconds: false,
    datepicker: false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7q26juzu/

Comment: Sorry. Its not working. Is this possible to set default time in changedate function?

Comment: Yes I need to set only time. But i want to set default time in "changeDate" function. How can I do this?

Comment: Please reply me how to set default time "00:00" in "changeDate" function.

Comment: Which plugin you are using, version what I using did not have a ChangeDate function, https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

Comment: I am using version v3.3.2

Comment: If I am going to add a new row means, I want to display selected date and default time "00:00" in textbox. Otherwise If already dates are there means I dont want to set time "00:00" from  there. The existing time only need to be display there.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of @Freddy's answer.

```
var dateNow = new Date();
$('#current_date').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate:moment(dateNow).startOf('hour')
});
```

`startof` can take various arguments. More details in MomentJS [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).