# Bootstrap datetimepicker default time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone had any luck in setting the default time in bootstrap datetimepicker?  https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I've tried [set default time in bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005455/set-default-time-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which is ok for the default date but as soon as you click another date it defaults back to the current time.

I want the date to default to today and time to default to 00:00, but if the user chooses another date then keep the time at 00:00, however they should be allowed to change it to something else.

Many thanks

Comment: Try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103965/set-default-time-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Perfect, thanks missed this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks @Josh Stewart for sending me to the solution, I missed that one: [Set default time in bootstrap datetimepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103965/set-default-time-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

```
var dateNow = new Date();
$('#current_date').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate:moment(dateNow).hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
});
```

Worked perfectly